# PHP / JQuery / AJAX for Updating Database if Div is not visible

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a complex website setup so I'll just make an example a simple one.

**Current Setup**

I have two buttons.

```
<a id="one" href="#">Link 1</a>
<a id="two" href="#">Link 2</a>
```

And I have two divs

```
<div id="showOne" style="display:none">1</div>
<div id="showTwo" style="display:none">2</div>
```

This is my JQuery code

```
$('#one').click(function (e) {
    $('#showOne').show();
});

$('#two').click(function (e) {
    $('#showTwo').show();
});
```

**What I'm Trying to Accomplish**

Basically, I have a database table setup that has a row to count how many times was div(showOne) and div(showTwo) shown.

How would I work with AJAX to add one to the database row aka counter if display = block?

**My Attempt**

```
$('#one').is(":visible")
{

$.ajax({

    type:"POST"
    url: update.php
    data: {type:link_one_shown}
    success: function(data){
      alert("Test");
    }

})
```

When I do this, the rest of my JQuery code crashes.  Not sure if this doesn't make sense or I just wrote something wrong.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: where is `if`? did you missed here `$('#one').is(":visible")` or ?

Comment: var counter = 0; function doSomthing() { alert(counter++); }; doSomthing(); doSomthing(); doSomthing(); // 1,2,3

Answer (score 2):

Three problems that I can see:

1. As Akam notes, you've mangled the `if` statement.
2. The `data` isn't correct -- `link_one_shown` should be either a variable (which you haven't defined?) or a string literal.
3. You're missing commas between the `ajax` function parameters.

---

Here's the modified code:

```
if ($('#showOne').is(":visible")) {
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: update.php,
        data: { type: "link_one_shown" },
        success: function(data){
          alert("Test");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Just close IF bracket or remove brackets since only one method is called in IF

Answer (score 0):

why not just move ajax call to function and invoke it when show the div, this avoids code repetition and makes it simpler.

```
$('#one').click(function (e) {
    $('#showOne').show();
    updateDB('link_one');
});

$('#two').click(function (e) {
    $('#showTwo').show();
    updateDB('link_two');
});


function updateDB(link)
{
    $.ajax({

        type:"POST"
        url: update.php
        data: {type:link}
        success: function(data){
          alert("Test");
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: Tried both and couldn't get it to work.  However, if I took the ajax part out and called an alert, it worked fine